# My App Status is Draft in Review on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, status, publishing

My App Status is in Draft and in Review on Google Play How do I change status, I have filled everything and gone for roll out. Pls help

Answer (score 4):

It means google is reviewing your app and I am guessing this is your first app on that console account, first app always take one week on more than one week.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is my 4th app and first time showing Draft

Comment: if your app break any policy than you got a option option for send for review otherwise it means google haven't review your app

Comment: I got the email too from IARC after submitting the App, there is no email or any other notification of breaking policy. I am not able to find option "send for review"

Comment: Problem solved, you have to leave as it is will review and approve automatically, the status will be changed to production..Thanks.